# Laravel $data is undefined error but i defineted it on fuctions

Tags: laravel-9

I have a data  `$data["dil1"]="Yasin";` and i added this data to title with `@section('title'){{$dil1}} - Yönetim Paneli @endsection` but i get this error message when i try to run codes: $dil1 is undefined

**How can i fix it ? or what's the main problem ?**

Thank you

[image: Controller Codes]

[image: Error]

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: Don't use `compact()`, just pass `$data`

Comment: Thank you guys so much and i would not use image for next time. Sorry about that

Comment: You're resetting/emptying your `$data` array _after_ you assigned values to it

Comment: Nothing happend accualy, there same error again :

´ public function dashboard(){
    $data["dil1"]="Yasin";
    $data = array();
    if (Session::has('loginId')) {
        $data = User::where ('id', '=', Session::get('loginId'))->first();
    }
    return view('panel/dashboard', $data);
   }´

Comment: So **don't** reset your array if you want to keep data in it. In addition you're **overwriting** your array with `$data = User...`. Use `dd($data)` to see what it contains.

Comment: Is there any method to keep to data with assigned values both on same function ?

Comment: Set `$data['dil1']` _after_ you possibly fetched the user data

Comment: I really dont know how can i give possite comment for you. but i wanna say that thank you so much. It make sense and works.